# Resolving a function call that generates a positional argument violation type error

Tags: python, function

I have defined a function that can accept a list of strings as an argument and apply methods to selectively output only strings that start with uppercase letters, however the function can only accept one list at a time.

However, if I call the function and pass it an argument with two lists, it returns:

```
TypeError: find_upper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is the function with a single list argument:

```
def find_upper(strlist):
    for string in strlist:
        for s in string:
            if s.isupper():
                print(string)
            else:
                continue

find_upper(['Marco', 'Billy', 'Petey Pelican', 'Chip Block', 'Ash'])
```

The following is the kind of two list argument that generates the aforementioned TypeError:

```
find_upper(['Red Robin', 'Baskin Robins', 'Applebees', 'McDonalds'], ['Jiffy Lube', 'Auto Zone', 'Christian Brothers Automotive', 'Firestone'])
```

Thank you for any helpful considerations that may clarify how to fix this. I feel like it's something simple right in front of me I'm just not seeing.

Comment: "The following is the kind of two list argument that generates the aforementioned TypeError:" What do you think should happen if you call the function that way? What do you want it to mean? " I feel like it's something simple right in front of me I'm just not seeing." Well, what happened when you tried *reading* the error message? Did you *understand* it? For example, do you know what a *positional argument* is?

Comment: If I understood I wouldn't be asking for clarification

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried copying and pasting `takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=takes+1+positional+argument+but+2+were+given)?

Comment: Examples where the error occurred in contexts that were not readily relatable to my function with solutions that didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: What he's trying to say is that if you define a function that takes exactly 1 argument, then you must call that function with exactly 1 argument.   Otherwise, your program logic is defective.  Your program SHOULD fail with an error message at that point - that's a GOOD THING and that's what you want, because that will guide you to fix your logic.  Python allows you to write a function with a variable number of arguments, but you have to design the function accordingly (see Sujay's answer).

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. This makes sense. I will add this to a flashcard in my coding deck. I'm still working on learning to follow logic with respect to outcomes and errors at a very basic, intro level. Thank you both.

Comment: I am not trying to say that; I am trying to get OP to realize that. There is no sanctimony involved. This is something called the Socratic method.

Comment: Alright, when you frame it that way, I see more what you're getting at. Socratic Method, nice.  I'll try to apply that approach to follow and see the logic behind the error and the solution, and hopefully improve the skill. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*args` which will accept any number of elements.
You know that `find_upper`is a function which accepts only one element. Instead, you could put the 2 lists in s separate list, iterate over that list and pass it in the function

```
def find_upper(*args):
    for strlist in args:
        for string in strlist:
            for s in string:
                if s.isupper():
                    print(string)
                else:
                    continue
```

You can do this to

```
def find_upper(strlist):
    for string in strlist:
        for s in string:
            if s.isupper():
                print(string)
            else:
                continue
my_list=[['Red Robin', 'Baskin Robins', 'Applebees', 'McDonalds'], ['Jiffy Lube', 'Auto Zone', 'Christian Brothers Automotive', 'Firestone']]
for i in my_list:
    find_upper(i)
```

Comment: The first code works great for both, and the second is quite clever. Thank you for helping me. You've been very helpful.